# Cannot create EC2 instance via Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I have the below template to create a simple ec2 instance. While creating the stack , I am getting the below error:

> Did not have IAM permissions to process tags on AWS::EC2::Instance resource

My template is below:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09

Description: Environment template v1.0 (c) xxx

Metadata:

  AWS::CloudFormation::Interface:
    ParameterGroups:      
      - Label:
          default: EC2/RDS parameters
        Parameters:
          - PresentationInstanceType
          - PresentationAMIId
    ParameterLabels:
      PresentationInstanceType:
        default: Instance type for presentation servers
      PresentationAMIId:
        default: Presentation instances AMI Id (Provided by AWS)


Parameters:

  PresentationInstanceType:
    Description: Provide valid AWS instance type.
    Type: String
  PresentationAMIId:
    Description: AWS Latest AMI Id. Do not change unless needed.
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>
    Default: /aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest/amzn2-ami-hvm-x86_64-gp2

Resources:
  
  MyEC2Instance: 
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties: 
      ImageId: !Ref PresentationAMIId
      InstanceType: !Ref PresentationInstanceType
      UserData:
        "Fn::Base64": !Sub |
          #!/bin/bash -xe
          apt-get update -y
```

Is there any idea why I am getting this error?

Comment: Is this full template? You are not using `cfn-init` or `cfn-signal` in your template, but yet you have them in your userdata?

Comment: Sorry. I updated the above code. This modified code also produces the same error

Answer (score 2):

There are no apparent issues with this template, except that you are using Amazon Linux 2 which does not use `apt`. So **correct userdata** is:

```
      UserData:
        "Fn::Base64": !Sub |
          #!/bin/bash -xe
          yum update -y
```

Your issue is about permissions, thus I can only speculate that you (or IAM role under which CFN executes) don't have suitable permissions to lunch such templates. Specifically those that are associated with instance tags, as CloudFormation will [autogenerate tags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-resource-tags.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a tag-based restriction policy and you are using Cloudformation to create the EC2 instance you have to use the LaunchTemplate as described here:
https://aws.amazon.com/it/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-ec2-iam-runinstances/